# Two servers configured in Hybris why? what is the purpose of these two servers

Tags: tomcat6, sap-commerce-cloud, tcserver

In `Hybris` two servers available.

One is `tcServer` and second is `tomcat` server.

What is the use of the two servers and why these two, and what are their purpose?

Is it mandatory to use these two?

Answer (score 1):

The gist is:
Hybris needs a web server to run in as all of its administrative interfaces (hac, hmc, cockpits, backoffice) are web UIs, but also a lot of customers will run webstores integrated with hybris.

Hybris supports both tomcat and tcServer as well as some other application servers, most notably Weblogic and WebSphere afaik.

The detailed information can be found on the hybris wiki, e.g.:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/SpringSource+tc+Server
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Third-Party+Application+Servers

Note that support always depends on the hybris version you end up using, but for tomcat and tcServer those are bundled with the hybris download.

(If you don't have a hybris wiki account yet, I strongly suggest you get one (it's free :) ) as you will find a lot of information there, plus there is also a forum at http://experts.hybris.com with quite some activity)

Hope this helps,

Sebastian

Comment: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/hybris+Server.      https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/SpringSource+tc+Server... https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/Oracle+WebLogic+10.3...... https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/IBM+WebSphere+7.0.. But in the suite default have two servers tcserver and tomcat but what is the benefit of tcserver.

Answer (score 1):

Both Hybris server (Tomcat) and tcServer come with hybris installation, you can select the one that fit your requirements (Tomcat is enough most of the time and I personally never used Tc Server).

---

### Hybris server (Tomcat)

- Default Hybris server
- Optimized and pre-configured server based on Apache Tomcat
- Production-ready quality and best suited to run all applications of the
  hybris Multichannel Suite
- Hybris Server Support is included in the standard hybris Service Level Agreements
- Independent of the operating system
- ...

---

### Tc Server

EDIT : main benefit is to simplify work at production site and provide advanced configuration like (multiple runtime instance from one binary).

Tc Server or SpringSource tcServer ([doc](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.5/getting-started/html/index.html)) is an enterprise version of Apache Tomcat

- Can be activated with : bundled.server.type=tcserver
- Simplifies work at production site (monitoring, deadlock detection, Garbage metrics, ams)

Comment: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/hybris+Server.      [https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/SpringSource+tc+Server... https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/Oracle+WebLogic+10.3...... https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/IBM+WebSphere+7.0.. But in the suite default have two servers tcserver and tomcat but what is the benefit of tcserver.

Comment: It has built-in tools for monitoring, it's based on Tomcat so it's not a big difference, The benefit in my EDIT

Answer (score 1):

Although hybris provides you 2 application servers (Tomcat & tcServer) to choose from and use for your development/testing, by default only Tomcat is configured to be used without doing any additional configuration i.e. when you build and run hybris server without any change in configuration, Tomcat is used. If you want to switch to tcServer (which is another powerful application server), you can update the configuration and switch to it as it is readily available in your hybris commerce suite download. In case, you like to use any other application server e.g. WebLogic, you will have to download it separately and deal with the licensing terms.

Thanks,
Arvind